# VSCode "Quick Open" menu alters "recently used" ordering too eagerly

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I step through the the VSCode Quick Open menu, I want it **not** to automatically switch between editors until I've selected the file I'm interested in (and hit `enter`).  But with a recent (April?) change to VSCode, it automatically shows me each file as I step through the menu.  How can I disable that behavior?

---

Here's my motivation, for those who are interested:

One of the (common?) ways to use VSCode's "Quick Open" menu is to use it like the "last channel" button on a TV remote.  I want to open one editor, then open another, and then quickly toggle back and forth between the two.  Since they are my current and most-recent editors, they should appear at the top of the Quick Open Menu, so toggling between them is fast.

This used to work just fine, but a recent (April?) change to the Quick Open menu seems to have broken this functionality.  Now, it automatically activates the editor for every file that I step through in the menu, changing my "most recent" ordering.  It can no longer be used like a "last channel" button.

Here's a short video demonstrating the problem.  Here, I'm starting with `one.txt`.  I want to select `five.txt` via the Quick Open menu, and then quickly toggle between the two.  But it opens all the other files along the way!

(In fact, if you watch closely, the behavior is even weirder: It doesn't show me the currently selected file -- it opens the editor for each file as it becomes UN-selected.  Maybe this is just a bug?)

[image: quick menu behavior animation]

FWIW, here are the the relevant parts of my `keybindings.json`, to make it clear which commands I'm referring to:

```
// keybindings.json
[
  // Trigger quick open menu and pre-select the previously used editor.
  // (With either cmd+left/cmd+right)
  {
    "key": "cmd+left",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup",
    "when": "!inEditorsPicker"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+right",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup",
    "when": "!inEditorsPicker"
  },

  // Once the menu is open, scan through the choices.
  // (Forward with cmd+right, backward with cmd+left)
  {
    "key": "cmd+left",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigatePreviousInEditorPicker",
    "when": "inEditorsPicker && inQuickOpen"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+right",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInEditorPicker",
    "when": "inEditorsPicker && inQuickOpen"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that my chosen key binding conflicts with a hard-coded key binding in VSCode.  A workaround is to just use a key other than the `right` arrow.

Explanation here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98479#issuecomment-633378132